Dynamically allocating an std vector of Eigen matrices whose sizes are known at compile time
I am writing a program to do some computationally-demanding calculations using the Eigen linear algebra library. Basically, I would like to diagonalize a large number of somewhat large (around 300 x 300) matrices in a loop. So, what I am trying to do is that before starting the loop, I allocate an STL container of a few Eigen matrices that I would like to reuse each iteration. The following code works:
std::vector<Eigen::Matrix<complex<double>, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic>> A; 
for (int i = 0; i < Imax; i++){
// some calculation using A 
}

However, I know the dimension of A and the size the STL vector at compile time. Would it be possible to allocate the vector of matrices dynamically before running the loop such that they have some fixed non-zero size? Basically, I have 4 elements in the vector, each one is a 300 x 300 Eigen matrix.

The contents of the eigen matrices are dynamically allocated, yes? If so, the size of the data store in the vector should be relatively small and you may be able to use std::array instead without killing the stack.

I just did that. It works. However, how do I fix the size of the dynamically allocated Eigen matrix? For example, if I have a single matrix, I can do Eigen::Matrix<std::complex, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic> Hk(100, 100) A; but for some reason I am not sure how to do so during the std::array declaration

std::array<Eigen::Matrix<std::complex<double>, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic>, 4> arr = {Eigen::Matrix<std::complex<double>, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic> Hk(100, 100), Eigen::Matrix<std::complex<double>, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic> Hk(100, 100), ...} would work, but it is excessively verbose. A alias could turn it into std::array<T,4> arr{T(100,100), T(100,100), ...}; A helper function could possibly shrink it further.

Stupid demo: https://godbolt.org/z/8zf6P7jW9

There is no reason to make your type definitions that verbose. Eigen has predefined type definitions for a reason. Just write std::vector<Eigen::MatrixXcd> or similarly std::array<Eigen::MatrixXcd, N>

From the comments:

you may be able to use std::array instead


I just did that. It works. However, how do I fix the size of the dynamically allocated Eigen matrix? For example, if I have a single matrix, I can do Eigen::Matrix<std::complex<double>, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic> Hk(100, 100) A; but for some reason I am not sure how to do so during the std::array

As I noted in the comments, you should use the predefined type definitions to shorten that code to std::vector<Eigen::MatrixXcd> or std::array<Eigen::MatrixXcd, N>. As for the main question of how to properly initialize: You can't do this directly without wasting runtime.
You might think that this works: A.fill(Eigen::MatrixXcd(300, 300)) (using std::array::fill) or A.assign(N, Eigen::MatrixXcd(300, 300)) with std::vector::assign but that creates pointless copies of uninitialized memory.
There may be some elaborate ways with fancy iterators / ranges, or template magic. But you can also just keep it simple:
std::array<Eigen::MatrixXcd, N> A;
for(auto& ai: A)
    ai.resize(300, 300);

There is no loss of performance. If you use parallelization and each entry goes to a different thread, delay the allocation until the specific thread can allocate its own memory. Helps with NUMA in particular.
You may also be tempted to use fully fixed matrices, e.g.
using Matrix300cd = Eigen::Matrix<std::complex<double>, 300, 300>;
std::array<Matrix300cd, N> A;

but don't do that!. 300x300 is too large for that to be necessary or reasonable.
